# Run node as background process from script running as child process

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, child-process

I'm running a node server on port 5100. It executes a shell script as child process which in turn starts another node server.

```
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
execFile("./testscript", args, {cwd: cwd}, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("error.." + error);
    console.log("stdout.." + stdout);
    console.log("stderr.." + stderr);
})
```

In script i'm running a node process by nohup as :

```
nohup node server.js PORT=5200 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null &
```

Now node@5200 has parentid of testscript which in turn has parentid of node@5100.
When i kill PID of node@5100 everything stops.

I want node@5200 to still run when testscript and node@5100 have exited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i spawned a process from a file that ran once, my child process had perfect behavior as parent file exited normally. 
Issue was raised as i was spawning process by a server file that was killed by Ctrl+c so it gave an error code on exit and as a result whole process group got SIGTERM which lead to killing of child process.

To successfully implement spawning i used double spawn i.e spawned a child process from my server file that further spawned child_process that ran my other node server. So i was able to avoid SIGTERM to reach grandchild and fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `detached` option when you create the child process.  This is sort of like `nohup`.  See the documentation here: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached

What this does is to make the child process the leader of a new "process group," so when the parent process group dies, the child can continue running.

Edit: the documentation says:

> When using the detached option to start a long-running process, the process will not stay running in the background unless it is provided with a stdio configuration that is not connected to the parent. If the parent's stdio is inherited, the child will remain attached to the controlling terminal.

So you must write code like this:

```
var child = spawn(cmd, args, {detached: true, stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'ignore']});

child.unref();
```

Or you can use their example to have stdout redirect to a file, etc.

Comment: child.unref() is not working as it shoould. Child isn't detached.

Comment: @vashishatashu: I've updated my answer with complete, tested code based on the docs.  The only part you were still missing was probably the `stdio` option.

Comment: I resolved this issue and will  give details in answer. I wasn't missing stdio.